# gpars withExistingPool

Tags: multithreading, groovy, gpars

I am trying to use gpars `GParsPool.withExistingPool` in gpars 0.12
It expects a `jsr166y.ForkJoinPool` but looks like in the jsr166y jar I have, there is no way to create that class(?). The only ones I can create are `jsr166y.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool` like so:

```
FJPool fjPool = new FJPool(2);
jsr166y.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool pool = fjPool.getForkJoinPool();// tried fjPool.createPool as well
```

Notice the packeage is different. So I get a method signature error when I try to run. Any idea how to overcome this?

Comment: You have version 1.7.0 of jsr166y?

Comment: Thats it, I had a newer version. Getting version 1.7.0 fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The ForkJoinPool class can be constructed directly using its constructor. Please, check that the following code works for you:

```
import jsr166y.ForkJoinPool
import groovyx.gpars.GParsPool

def pool = new ForkJoinPool()
GParsPool.withExistingPool(pool) {
    println ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5].anyParallel{it > 3})
}
```

If not, I can only think of you using an incompatible version of jsr166y. The correct one is identified as 'org.codehaus.jsr166-mirror:jsr166y:1.7.0'.

Vaclav